# Correct way to handle missing data in boto3 response with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, error-handling, boto3

I am writing some python code to do some stuff with AWS autoscaling groups and such.  I have several functions that will use boto3 to call to aws and get back a dict from which I want to extract one value.  The value is of course deep in the hierarchy.  I realized the code I wrote to deal with the possibility that any of the hierarchy keys are missing won't do diddly as python will throw an exception first.  So what is the best way to deal with something like this.  Below is the code I have that doesn't really do what it implies it would do.

```
def get_asg_launch_template_id(asg_client, asg_name):
  try:
    response = asg_client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=[asg_name])
    launch_template_id = response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['LaunchTemplate']['LaunchTemplateId']
    if launch_template_id is None:
      msg = "Failed to find LaunchTemplateId in the output of describe_auto_scaling_groups"
      logger.error(msg)
      logger.debug("Output:", response)
      raise ValueError(msg)
    return launch_template_id
  except ClientError as e:
    logger.error("Error calling Autoscaling client to get the launch template id from the ASG")
    raise e
```

What is the best (and most readable) way to get the value or report a meaningful infromation if I can't.

Comment: `launch_template_id = response['AutoScalingGroups'][0].get('LaunchTemplate', {}).get('LaunchTemplateId', None) if response['AutoScalingGroups']`

Comment: How do the get's differ?  Do they not throw an exception or something if what they are looking for isn't there?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Sweet, and thanks for the link.  Googling "python get" just gives me tons of sites that have what we can call "loose" definitions without the real details.  That link is concise and detailed at the some time.

Comment: I improved the code based on this idea.  And I found out that lists don't have a get function.  So now that list seems to be the problem.  Apparently adding a get to lists was rejected.  That makes me wonder, am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?  Thinking maybe I should just wrap the assignment in it's own try so I can log the error.

Comment: `(response.get('AutoScalingGroups', [])+[{}])[0].get('LaunchTemplate', {}).get('LaunchTemplateId', None)` If you really want to (mostly) safely query both the array and dictionaries.  This pattern will fail if any of the elements in the chain is not a list or dictionary when you expect them.

Comment: @Randell I used the `if` statement for the list check.

Comment: @jordanm  The if actually didn't work when I tested it.  If the key didn't exist it threw an exception.  Fixing that ended up being a get check for the first key, then a len check, then another get check for what remains.  That got ugly fast, which made me wonder if I was doing something people just don't do for some reason.

Comment: Verbose null checking of external data isn't wrong or uncommon